# Does a Linux server use swap space of an SSH client?

Tags: ssh, swap

I currently am SSHing into a Linux server via my mac's terminal program. Afterwards, I run whatever simulations and calculations I need to do.

However, I noticed that after I log in, it says on the top that the Linux server has: 30 GB RAM, 10 GB Swap.

Does anyone know what this swap term means? Does it mean it will use some of my computer's partition for running things?

I ask this because my computer becomes incredibly slow and low on memory whenever I run a memory intensive job. Thanks!

Comment: The Linux server has 10GB swap. That's swap on that server. It has nothing to do with your Mac. The server does not (and cannot) use your computer to swap (not without doing a lot of configuration first).

Comment: Do you really think the server pushes such a lot of data to the client side only in order to retrieve it back at a later time?

Answer (score 1):

If you are out of RAM, the swap space will use disk as virtual memory. Pretending disk is memory will be slow.

The alternative is to remove the swap space from the system and then there likely won't be enough memory and your program will terminate, be terminated by the system or fault; even worse, it could generate wrong answers which would really suck.

Buy more memory. Ssh has absolutely nothing to do with it.